# Issues editing Sharepoint 2007 on a Mac

Tags: 2007, chrome, apple-ios, firefox

I've just had a MacBook Pro with Yosemite set up for work, I regularly edit our company SharePoint site which runs on SharePoint 2007 but having trouble doing this compared to using IE on the work laptop I used previously.

In Safari, Chrome and Firefox I have issues with modifying webparts, the webpart editor menu doesn't appear, and I have no toolbar when trying to use content editor webparts, there's no editing toolbar and it gives me the html editor box instead.

I only do basic things on our Intranet like creating pages (using a custom built template), creating and maintaining sites etc. I'm no html whizz so need the ability to use the front end editing tools.

I've tried using the developer tools on Safari to replicate an IE environment but no luck, and none of the IE extensions with Chrome and Firefox seem to work.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Ed

Answer (score 4):

Safari / Firefox considered as Level 2 browsers for SharePoint 2007.

Level 2 Web browsers provide basic functionality so that users can both read and write in SharePoint sites and perform site administration. However, ActiveX controls are supported only in level 1 browsers.

It is advisable to use IE browser for SharePoint 2007.

You can refer this link for more information: [Plan browser support (Office SharePoint Server)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(v=office.12).aspx)